# c++ __asm code (How to transfer double to ax)

Tags: c++, assembly

This may sound stupid or lazyness. I know that ax register is 16bit and double is 64bit. How do I transfer the double to ax using __asm? The question is more of, how I do i break them to 4(16 bits) or maybe access the 3(16 bits) to go into ax of the double using asm?

Part2
How do i transfer 16bit (bitwise) back to i?

```
int main(void)
{
  double i= 0;

  __asm
  {
    MOV ax, i;
    //Some calucation
    MOV i, ax;
  }
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Lastly, what is MOVSX, and MOVSZ

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Oh, and additionally, why are you using `AX`, rather than `rax` or `eax`?

Comment: Let say, my double i= 70, 000.0; I want to transfer to my AX to perform some arithmatic calculation. However, AX only contain 16 bits and therefore there is a need to shift the the 4 * 16 bits of double to ax so that i can access their data.  How can I achieve this goal using asm?

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have to ask in a different way: Assuming you have 70000 in i, what do you expect the output to be at the end? What math are you attempting to do?

Comment: Maybe perfrom some i * i? or maybe double b= 1; in __asm  a < b in asm some cmp jne stuff

Comment: It's not clear what sort of calculation you intend to perform, because putting a floating point value in an integer register isn't useful for calculation in general.

Comment: Right, a floating (using 64-bit value) point multiply using 16-bit registers is far from trivial. Nor is comparisons. If you are looking for something that is less than 50 lines of (tricky) assembler code, you are probably not understanding the problem very well.

Comment: Do you want the bits of the encoded double in AX because you are manipulating the floating-point representation or do you want the value of the floating-point number converted to integer and placed in AX because you are doing some arithmetic on it?

Comment: Hi, Eric. Yes that is what I am trying to do. Or how to split the bit of int so that i can placed in AX for some computation

Comment: @user2306421: I am sorry, but you answered an “X or Y?” question with “Yes”. You need to state one of “X” or “Y”. You should choose 1 or 2: 1. You want the bits of the encoding. 2. You want the integer portion of the represented value. Also, if you respond with @ and user name, the user will be notified, when they next visit Stack Overflow. (When there is a space, as in my user name, omit it, using “@EricPostpischil”.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the value of the double to a 16 bit int:-

```
double d=3.1415;
__asm
{
  push ax
  fld [d]
  fistp word ptr [esp]
  pop ax ; ax = 3
}
```

and to get the value as a 32 bit int:-

```
double d=3.1415;
__asm
{
  push eax
  fld [d]
  fistp dword ptr [esp]
  pop eax ; eax = 3
}
```

If you want to get the bit wise representation of the least significant bits of the floating point value:-

```
double d=3.1415;
__asm
{
  lea edx,[d]
  mov ax,[edx] ; for the lowest 16 bits
  mov eax,[edx] ; for the lowest 32 bits
  mov eax,[edx+4] ; for bits 32-63
  ; etc
}
```

But this is not as useful, and very tricky to deal with, unless you're doing something like the infamous inv-sqrt trick (which probably doesn't gain much speed on very modern processors).

Note: This was all written using DevStudio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use bitmasks and bitshifts to store the 16 bits of your choice in the ax register. In this situation, you will have to consider whether or not the bitshifts change your number from a negative to a positive (use shift right arithmetic). To move the value back, use bitwise or on i and ax after you have moved it to the proper position (maybe in a 64
bit register) using bitshifts to the left.

Answer (score 0):

"I know that ax register is 16bit and double is 64bit. How do I transfer the double to ax using __asm?"

A byte is 8

A word is 16

A double word is 32

A quad word is 64

So you must be saying "a double double word" is 64

As far as getting it into ax is concerned I would look at chucking the 64 bits onto the stack then taking 4x 16 bit ax bites out of it, or 2x 32bit eax bites kinda thing

Bear in mind that your operating system will decide the size of your pops unless you use the stack address as a pointer

16bit pop moves the pointer by 2bytes

32bit pop moves the pointer by 4 bytes

edit:
If you want to do monster registers then you need to look at and study adc and sbb which would allow a 16bit unit to do 64bit numbers and a 32 bit unit to manipulate 128 bit numbers

So in 16 bit you would create an ax-bx-cx-dx register (wow)